Azure DevOps Pipeline Showing Unspecified Results for MSTest Data-Driven Tests
I'm facing an issue with data-driven MSTest functional tests in my Azure DevOps pipeline. The pipeline uses Visual Studio Test Platform version 17.2.0 to execute the tests. All the tests are failing with the result status being shown as "unspecified".
Here are the relevant details:
Test Framework: MSTest-based functional tests.
Pipeline Setup: Using the Visual Studio Test task in the Azure DevOps pipeline.
Agent: Microsoft-hosted agent.
Troubleshooting Steps I Tried:
Verified that all dependencies and configurations are correct.
Ensured the MSTest framework version matches the test project’s requirements.
Reviewed the task logs, which show the tests are executed but without proper status updates for certain tests.
My Questions:
Has anyone encountered similar issues with data-driven tests showing unspecified results?
Is this related to a known bug or compatibility issue between MSTest and the Visual Studio Test Platform task?
Are there any recommended settings or workarounds to ensure all results are properly published?
Any guidance or help would be greatly appreciated!

Hi, please share the pipeline yaml and the debug log (set the variable system.debug to true)?  If possible, can you please share a Minimal, Reproducible code example  to better troubleshooting the issue? To test the issue, I created a simple MSTest project and use the Visual Studio Test task in my pipeline, it works without error.

@MiaoTian-MSFT, I had a discussion with MSFT internal team. There is a change made in the way how data driven tests are to be shown post 2.2.3 version of MsTest adapter. Earlier it used to be in hierarchical format, but post this it will be flat hierarchy and I think it is because of this it is showing that way in the UI

Hi @Pulkit Sharma. thanks for sharing this update! Have they provided any solution about the issue? If there is a solution, you can share the solution by posting an answer.  If you are still trouble shooting, maybe you can try to use the old version of MsTest adapter and see if it works. This may help to narrow down the issue.

@MiaoTian-MSFT the didn't have any solution for now. I tried with older version ( 2.1.2 )  and things are working.

Hi @Pulkit Sharma. Thanks for the update. It seems that the problem is indeed caused by the new version of MsTest adapter, as the old version works fine. You can use the old version as a temporary workaround and give them feedback that this new version needs to be fixed.
